# Electron for MAS (Mac app store)

Tags: electron, mac-app-store

After doing a lot of research I've found that in order to build an electron app for the Mac App Store, it requires a special build of Electron. Previously though I've only used electron-prebuilt installed via npm.

Is there a way to install the mac app store version via npm or is there a pre-built version? I can't seem to find any such packages. I do notice the full code is here https://github.com/atom/electron/releases but, it would be nicer to have the dependencies remain in my package.json if possible.  Is there a recommended way to set this up?

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to install electron-packager to package the app:

```
npm install -g electron-packager
```

Then, use:

```
electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=<Electron version> [optional flags...]
```

to package the app.

**Note:** replace arch with `ia32` if you're packaging for 32-bit, or `all` to package for both.

Finally, you need to follow the [guide](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide.md) for submission (and the [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html) one).

Answer (score 2):

If you use electron-forge for packaging, you can run package command with parameter `--platform=mas` which will package your app with the right version of electron for Mac App store. I have done it successfully with my electron application.

```
electron-forge package --platform=mas
```